# wxWidgets is not playing video with unicode path

Tags: video, unicode

We are creating installer in which we play a video. We are using wxWidgets for playing the video. This works fine if the package is present under English path but fails for Chinese path(Unicode). Even If the file name contains Unicode character it fails.

We tried with both .mp4 and .wmv video format fails for both.

Note: The executable that we creating is non Unicode app. We can not make this to Unicode since there is lot of dependencies on this app.

I found related information in [this site](http://wxpython-users.wxwidgets.narkive.com/rAHBL8XC/unicode-windows-mediactrl-and-quicktime) but it didn't help me.

I have one more question on restricting video controls. As mentioned on [this site](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_media_ctrl.html) I used  `m_mediactrl->ShowPlayerControls(wxMEDIACTRLPLAYERCONTROLS_NONE)` to disable video controls from UI. But I could see the video controls for fraction of seconds at the beginning and at the end of the video.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is probably converting the Unicode path in the old 8.3 format by using the `GetShortPathName` function from the Windows API.